# Split Alphabets and Numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in Excel that looks like this:

```
X2014
X2014
XF2014
XF2014
X2014
```

I want to transform this column to:

```
X14
X14
XF14
XF14
X14
```

All I want to do is to remove the 2014 and make it 14 (and all other years e.g 2015 to 15, 2099 to 99 etc). Can someone please help with a solution without the REPLACE function?

Comment: No its not broken. I want a code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *[SUBSTITUTE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/substitute-function-HP010062578.aspx)*.

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"20","")`

This will replace all occurrence of *20* (we omitted the optional argument *instance*). 
Specify *instance* if you just need 1 occurrence replaced. HTH.

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit1:** Considering all years

```
=SUBSTITUTE( A1,
            MID( A1, MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$20),1)),0),4),
            RIGHT(MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$20),1)),0),4),2)
           )
```

**Edit2:** *I realized above can be further simplified to:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$20),1)),0),2),"")
```

You can use above formula which will work on all years.
It is an array formula; copy in formula bar then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. HTH.

**Result2:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this function will not work in the year 3014 or 3114.

Comment: @user2923027 You should've constructed your question clearer. Ok let's see how we can tweak it to your needs.